# Issues with vif-nat and Xen after upgrading from Debian 8 to 10

Tags: debian, xen, debian-buster

I'm getting this error when running `xl create`:

```
# xl create ../vm-www.rootspirit.com.cfg
Parsing config from ../vm-www.rootspirit.com.cfg
libxl: error: libxl_exec.c:118:libxl_report_child_exitstatus: /etc/xen/scripts/vif-nat online [12721] exited with error status 1
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1286:device_hotplug_child_death_cb: script: /etc/xen/scripts/vif-nat failed; error detected.
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:1520:domcreate_attach_devices: Domain 32:unable to add vif devices
```

My VIF config looks like this:

```
vif = [ 'ip=172.16.1.51,mac=11:11:23:44:23:52,script=vif-nat', 'ip=2001:1AF8:3100:A00A:21::2000,mac=43:32:11:23:70:20,script=vif-bridge,bridge=xenbr0' ]
```

But anything that includes `script=vif-nat` or `script=vif-route` fails with the above error.

The package `iproute2` and `net-tools` are installed. Logs don't show anything.

The `xl -vvvv` command is [here](https://pastebin.com/LE5z3SCN).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the `vif-nat` script crashes. I have resolved the problem by creating my own internal network.

Dom0:

```
allow-hotplug xenbr1
auto xenbr1
iface xenbr1 inet static
        address 10.13.37.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

xen configs:

- Public and LAN DomU: `vif = [ 'ip=1.2.3.4,bridge=xenbr0', 'ip=10.13.37.123,bridge=xenbr1' ]`
- LAN only DomU: `vif = [ 'ip=10.13.37.123,bridge=xenbr1' ]`

iptables should be something along the lines of:

```
iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface xenbr1 -j ACCEPT
iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface xenbr0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And of course config the static IP in network settings of the DomU.